# How to perform stemming/lemming on GAE-search application?

Tags: google-app-engine, stemming, gae-search

I am trying to implement stemming in my search app. I have already tried using ~ operator, but it didn't work.

So, I have 3 questions:

1) Should I index a document in some special way to be able to search it using ~ operator? I have a document contained "words", but it can't be found with query="~word".

2) Does operator ~ support other languages?

3) Would you suggest to use other stemmer/lemmer but not the built-in one?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The stemming operator ~ does work, at least for finding the word "words" with the query ~word.

Are you putting "~word" in quotes in the query?  That would disable stemming.

Also, I forgot to mention previously, stemming isn't currently implemented in the Development Servers; it only works in the real App Engine environment hosted by Google.